# PHP Displaying Name from Database to page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to pull data from my database like their First name and Last name and make it display on my webpage. This is my php inside of my html markup.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    require './includes/dbh.inc.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<li class='login current2'><a href='login.php'>". $row['fnidusers'] . $row['lnidusers'] ."</a></li>";
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "<li class='login current2'><a href='login.php'>Login / Sign up</a></li>";
}
?>
```

I'm attempting to make a drop down with their name as the label for it. For example:
[image: Amazons Example]

Amazon has similar drop down that I'm looking for, It says the name of the user.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Right now your code seems to select all users and print something for each. If you simply want the logged in user, you should alter your query to select the name of the user with id equal to the session-userid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display only the current logged in user, you can do it with your request like this :

`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "'"`

Here you are searching in all rows, the one with id the current logged in user id.

Now, just reuse the var in your while but without the while :

`$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Now your code will look something like this :

```
<?php
require './includes/dbh.inc.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    $resut = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "'");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "<li class='login current2'><a href='login.php'>". $row['fnidusers'] . $row['lnidusers'] ."</a></li>";
    }
} else
    echo "<li class='login current2'><a href='login.php'>Login / Sign up</a></li>";
?>
```

Please excuse my bad english ^^